# Does Godot support python?

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

Can you please tell me in detail whether Godot support python or no, because i don't know C#, I only have 2 choices; if Godot supports python, I will go with it, if not I will try to learn GDscript, And whether if python is supported, should I go with GDscript or python. Thanks you.

Comment: why did you tag unity then?

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the [Godot documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/about/faq.html#which-programming-languages-are-supported-in-godot), Python is not officially supported, but there is [this project](https://github.com/touilleMan/godot-python) to provide a Python binding.

However, as far as I can tell, GDScript is very Python-like in that you might not have that much trouble in simply starting GDScropt from your Python experience.

(Also, the Python binding mentioned above doesn't seem to work yet together with Godot 4, so you might be better off with GDScript for the time being.)